# Datanode is in dead state as DFS used is 100 percent

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am having a standalone setup of Apache Hadoop with Namenode and Datanode running in the same machine.

I am currently running Apache Hadoop 2.6 (I cannot upgrade it) running on Ubuntu 16.04.

Although my system is having more than 400 GB of Hard disk left but my Hadoop dashboard is showing 100%.

Why Apache Hadoop is not consuming the rest of the disk space available to it? Can anybody help me figuring out the solution.
[image: Dashboar Image]

[image: Dashboard Image 2]

[image]

Comment: what is the output of jps?

Comment: it is showing the process ID

Comment: But in UI it is showing a lot of missing blocks

Comment: Where are your datanode directories mounted from the shown image? `vg-root`?

Comment: ya, same machine

Answer (score 0):

There can be certain reasons for it.

You can try following steps:

1. Goto $HADOOP_HOME/bin
2. ./hadoop-daemon.sh --config $HADOOP_HOME/conf start datanode

Then you can try the following things:-

1. If any directory other than your namenode and datanode directories taking up too much space, you can start cleaning up
   Also you can run hadoop fs -du -s -h /user/hadoop (to see usage of the directories).
2. Identify all the unnecessary directories and start cleaning up by running hadoop fs -rm -R /user/hadoop/raw_data (-rm is to delete -R is to delete recursively, be careful while using -R).
3. Run hadoop fs -expunge (to clean up the trash immediately, some times you need to run multiple times).
4. Run hadoop fs -du -s -h / (it will give you hdfs usage of the entire file system or you can run dfsadmin -report as well - to confirm whether storage is reclaimed)

Many times it shows missing blocks ( with replication 1).